# SBT: value vs apply

Tags: scala, sbt

It seems that these are equivalent:

```
someKey <<= someOtherKey(_ / "foo")
```

and

```
someKey := someOtherKey.value / "foo"
```

Are these the same?

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are the same. The former syntax is the old way of doing things (sbt <= 0.12). You should prefer the latter, which is more readable, and the normal style for sbt >= 0.13.

Comment: Hm, I've actually thought the first is more readable, as it doesn't requiring constantly remembering whether I'm in a "context" of sorts that works for `.value`. (Not to mention shorter, at least in my example.) Is there a source that says the latter is preferred?

Comment: Waw, you must be the only one on earth preferring the old style ^^ I remember when everyone was *relieved* when 0.13 introduced `.value`. Anyway, for sources, well for starters the fact that the current documentation doesn't even mention the old syntax. And the [release notes of 0.13](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#New+task%2Fsetting+syntax) made it pretty clear too, I believe.

Comment: Haha. Maybe. It's clearer to me that it is operating on a future value of of the setting, based on scope, etc., which a core concept of SBT. In contrast, the .value mechanism took a macro to implement. But I agree .value is cleaner.